# PHP Warning: require_once(WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/BlockList.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage

I have used [azure-sdk-for-php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php%20library) library and I am getting this error-Warning: require_once(WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/BlockList.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

My code is as below-

```
define("__BLOBNAME__", "BLOBNAME");
define("__CONTAINERNAME__", "CONTAINERNAME");
define("__BLOBKEY__", "BLOBKEY");

//require_once('WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php');
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
use WindowsAzure\Common\CloudConfigurationManager;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\Block;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\ListContainersOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CommitBlobBlocksOptions;

use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\BlobProperties;


$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" . __BLOBNAME__ . ";AccountKey=" . __BLOBKEY__ . "";

if (null == $connectionString || "" == $connectionString) {
    echo "Did not find a connection string whose name is 'StorageConnectionString'.";
    exit();
}

// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

try {
    // List blobs.
    $blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs(__CONTAINERNAME__);
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    // iterate over blobs
    foreach ($blobs as $blob) {
        $options = new WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions();
        $options->setBlobCacheControl("public, max-age=604800");
        echo 'setting ... ';
        $blobRestProxy->setBlobProperties(__CONTAINERNAME__,$blob->getName(), $options);
    }

} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code . ": " . $error_message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you failed to load the SDK file.

The recommended way to resolve dependencies is to install them using the [Composer package manager](http://getcomposer.org/).

- Create a file named **composer.json** in the root of your project and add the following code to it:

  `json
  {
    "require": {

        "microsoft/windowsazure": "^0.5"
    }

  }`
- Download **[composer.phar](http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar)** in your project root.
- Open a command prompt and execute this in your project root

  `php composer.phar install`

Then load the SDK in your code with:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```